# Extracting a string from a nested dictionary in presto

Tags: sql, dictionary, nested, presto

I have data that looks like this:

```
WITH raw_string AS (
    
    SELECT '{
        "484934206380132":["__time__":"1657740233","__qtype__":"message"]
        ,"492645072399511":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"386574019969974":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1043183892945050":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Kick-off call\",\"Creative presentation\",\"Design Sessions\",\"Final deliverables (assets)\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"3184511478430353":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Making ads for Meta platforms\",\"Producing video content\",\"Applying mobile creative best practices\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"1115358562640462":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"radio"}
        ,"392599788967548":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"dropdown"}
        ,"318278303702075":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"07132022","__qtype__":"numeric_field"},"2629866570491655":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"checkbox"}
        ,"481522393704422":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"Total Bet","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1091749101368816":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"The collaborative work","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"503986774424936":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        }' AS question_context
) 

SELECT * FROM raw_string
```

I'd like to extract "subquestions" into separate rows (in an sql table):
-- Making ads for Meta platforms
-- Producing video content
-- Applying mobile creatives best...

I have a tried a few functions json_extract_scalar, and Map functions etc, but I didn't succeed.

Thanks in advance for your help.

So the thing I was doing, which is a bit convoluted and leads to an incorrect solution is this:

```
WITH raw_string AS (
    
    SELECT *
    FROM
     (VALUES ('{
        "484934206380132":["__time__":"1657740233","__qtype__":"message"]
        ,"492645072399511":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"386574019969974":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1043183892945050":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Kick-off call\",\"Creative presentation\",\"Design Sessions\",\"Final deliverables (assets)\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"3184511478430353":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Making ads for Meta platforms\",\"Producing video content\",\"Applying mobile creative best practices\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"1115358562640462":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"radio"}
        ,"392599788967548":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"dropdown"}
        ,"318278303702075":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"07132022","__qtype__":"numeric_field"},"2629866570491655":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"checkbox"}
        ,"481522393704422":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"Total Bet","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1091749101368816":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"The collaborative work","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"503986774424936":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        }')) AS question_cntxt(questions_context)
) 

SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM raw_string
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(questions_context) AS t(qn_id, sub_qn)
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sub_qn) as t(category, _values)
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(_values, ',')) AS t(_levels)
```

I come close to what am trying to do, but I end up with a lot more rows than I need. I think I'm getting closer though.

The thing am really trying to do is put together a datasets of questions and answers. I want to pair them up together nicely.

The data looks like this::

```
    
    SELECT *
    FROM
     (VALUES ('{
        "484934206380132":["__time__":"1657740233","__qtype__":"message"]
        ,"492645072399511":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"386574019969974":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1043183892945050":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Kick-off call\",\"Creative presentation\",\"Design Sessions\",\"Final deliverables (assets)\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"3184511478430353":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Making ads for Meta platforms\",\"Producing video content\",\"Applying mobile creative best practices\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"1115358562640462":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"radio"}
        ,"392599788967548":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"dropdown"}
        ,"318278303702075":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"07132022","__qtype__":"numeric_field"},"2629866570491655":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"checkbox"}
        ,"481522393704422":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"Total Bet","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1091749101368816":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"The collaborative work","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"503986774424936":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        }', 
        '{"1043183892945050":["Very satisfied","Very satisfied","Very satisfied","Very satisfied"]
        ,"1091749101368816":["All participants are engaging and open to feedback. The agency is ready to accept suggestions and proactively suggest ideas as well."]
        ,"1115358562640462":["5 - Very Satisfied"],"2629866570491655":["Yes",null,null]
        ,"318278303702075":["07122022"]
        ,"3184511478430353":["Somewhat confident","Somewhat confident","Somewhat confident"]
        ,"386574019969974":["NA"],"392599788967548":["Asia Pacific (APAC)"],"481522393704422":["Genero"]
        }'
        )) AS question_cntxt(questions, answers)
) 

SELECT * FROM raw_string
```

I want to create a table where in the end I have a question:

```
|qn_id           | category.           |Answer          |
|----------------|---------------------|----------------|
|1043183892945050|Kick-off call.       | Very Satisfied.|
|1043183892945050|Creative presentation| Very satisfied |
|1043183892945050|Design sessions.     | Very satisfied |
|1043183892945050|Final deri.          | very sat.      |
```

I was trying to take a shot at it one column at a time

Comment: `"484934206380132":["__time__":"1657740233","__qtype__":"message"]` - That is not a valid json.

Comment: What are you suggesting Mr Stron? I tried Cross Join Unnest(question_context) and have been running with that for now. But I still don't gave a correct solution. Am working on it. I find the documentation on this very skimpy.

Comment: Please show the code and what errors/incorrect results did it give you.

Comment: Thanks Guru, I'll study your solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the json (the first property for some reason contains mailformed array, not another json object), you can do next:

```sql
WITH raw_string AS (
    
    SELECT '{
        "484934206380132":{"__time__":"1657740233","__qtype__":"message"}
        ,"492645072399511":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"386574019969974":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1043183892945050":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Kick-off call\",\"Creative presentation\",\"Design Sessions\",\"Final deliverables (assets)\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"3184511478430353":{"__time__":"1657740228","subquestions":"[\"Making ads for Meta platforms\",\"Producing video content\",\"Applying mobile creative best practices\"]","__qtype__":"ratingmatrix"}
        ,"1115358562640462":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"radio"}
        ,"392599788967548":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"dropdown"}
        ,"318278303702075":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"07132022","__qtype__":"numeric_field"},"2629866570491655":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"checkbox"}
        ,"481522393704422":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"Total Bet","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"1091749101368816":{"__time__":"1657740228","translation":"The collaborative work","__qtype__":"text"}
        ,"503986774424936":{"__time__":"1657740228","__qtype__":"text"}
        }' AS question_context
) 

SELECT subquestion
FROM (
    SELECT map_values( -- get values which is in turn array of maps
        map_filter( -- get only records with subquestions
            cast(json_parse(question_context) as map(varchar, map(varchar, varchar))),
            (k, v)->element_at(v, 'subquestions') is not null
        )
    ) mp_arr
    FROM raw_string
) p
, unnest(mp_arr) as t(mp) -- unnest array of maps
, unnest(cast(json_parse(mp['subquestions']) as array(varchar))) as tt(subquestion) -- 'subquestions' are double encoded so need to decode them
```

Output:

| subquestion |
| --- |
| Kick-off call |
| Creative presentation |
| Design Sessions |
| Final deliverables (assets) |
| Making ads for Meta platforms |
| Producing video content |
| Applying mobile creative best practices |